# How to Check if a Column Contains a List in Pandas (Python)?

Tags: python, pandas

When I run a `drop_duplicates` on my DataFrame I am getting an `unhashable type: list` error. It's because my `df` contains lists. However, it's non-obvious to me that it does. When I run `df.dtypes` the columns return as `object`.

I could do `df.apply(lambda x: str(x) if isinstance(x, list) else x)`, which stringifies everything. However there are other unhashable types I would have to try. Like, for all I know there are dictionaries or tuples holding mutables, and these would give the same error

In order to overcome this, I have had to manually inspect my df to figure which columns are list, and handle them accordingly (dropping them worked).I don't like this. Is there an easier pandas command to return columns containing lists? For example, might there be something like, if my dataframe is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'a', [1,2,3]], [2, "b", [4,5,6]]], columns = ["number", "letter", "unhashable"])
```

Which looks like:

```
    number  letter  unhashable
0   1   a   [1, 2, 3]
1   2   b   [4, 5, 6]
```

Then there's a method I can run on `df`, something like `df.detailed_dtypes`, to give me back

```
number: int,
letter: str,
unhashable: list
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with

```
df.iloc[0].map(lambda x : type(x).__name__)
Out[136]: 
number        int64
letter          str
unhashable     list
Name: 0, dtype: object
```